# Hide All Windows by Default in SwiftUI macOS App

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am working on a new SwiftUI-only menu bar application and stumbled into the following problem; Whenever I define either a Window or WindowGroup in SwiftUI, at least one window is always opened on app launch. Conditional rendering (like if x { Window() }) isn't supported either. The app should have an onboarding Window that is only shown depending on a user defaults setting. And there should be another window that can be manually opened via the menu bar item.

This is my SwiftUI App's class:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow
    @AppStorage("showIntroduction") private var showIntroduction = true

    init() {
        if showIntroduction {
            print("Show introduction")
            openWindow(id: "introduction")
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        // How to hide this window by default?
        Window("Intro", id: "introduction") {
            WelcomeView()
        }
            .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
        Settings {
            SettingsView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra {
            MenuBarView()
        } label: {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Views have the .hidden() modifier - but this doesn't support Windows or WindowGroups. When my view is hidden but wrapped in a Window or WindowGroup an empty window is rendered instead.

Is there any way to achieve this with plain SwiftUI? Or is it necessary to programmatically create and open an NSWindow if it shouldn't be open by default?

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a way to do this in pure SwiftUI.

However, here is a light weight approach with `NSWindow`:

```
import SwiftUI

var welcomeWindow: NSWindow?

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @AppStorage("showIntroduction") private var showIntroduction = true
    
    init() {
        if showIntroduction {
            print("Show introduction")
            
            welcomeWindow = NSWindow()
            welcomeWindow?.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: WelcomeView())
            welcomeWindow?.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "introduction")
            welcomeWindow?.styleMask = [.closable, .titled]
            welcomeWindow?.isReleasedWhenClosed = true
            welcomeWindow?.center()
            welcomeWindow?.becomeFirstResponder()
            welcomeWindow?.orderFrontRegardless()
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {        
        Settings {
            SettingsView()
                .navigationTitle("Settings")
        }
        MenuBarExtra {
            MenuBarView()
        } label: {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's no dedicated `Window` Scene.

If you don't like the titled, closable design, you can close the window with this function in your `WelcomeView`, e.g. on a `Button`:

```
Button("Done") {
    NSApp.windows.filter { $0.identifier?.rawValue == "introduction" }.first?.close()
}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, however you lose things like adding commands to the scene or reuse everything for a multiplatform app.

Comment: I don't know if *menu-bar app* and *multiplatform* go together well, so is it really a loss? But I admit these are not more than workarounds and building a menu-bar app is much easier if you stay in a plain AppDelegate lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested. Not nice but after hours of frustration to get such a no brainer done my only way that worked at least for me:

1. App code, connect Application Delegate

   ```
   @main
   struct ResolutionSwitcherApp: App {
       @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

       init() {
       }

       var body: some Scene {
           Window("Settings", id: "settings-window") {
               ContentView()
                   //.frame(width: 350, height: 250)
                   .frame(minWidth: 800, minHeight: 600)
                   .environmentObject(theModel)
           }
           .windowResizability(.contentSize)


           MenuBarExtra( "Resolution Switcher", systemImage: "dot.scope.display") {
               AppMenu()
                   .environmentObject(theModel)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In AppDelegate overwrite applicationDidFinishLaunching, find "your" window and close it.

   ```
   class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
       func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
           // Note: main window is nil
           //let w = NSApp.mainWindow

           let a = NSApp.windows
           if( a.count > 0 ) {
               let window : NSWindow = a[0]
               let title = window.title
               window.close()
           }
       }    
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure you need the `onAppear`? It seems to me that the AppDelegate is doing all the work.

Comment: @idolize thx, you are right. I removed it in the answer. It was a left over from the many things I tried out prior to get it working :)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Declare your app as menu bar utility**

put this in your info.plist or info tab in project settings:

```
Application is agent (UIElement) YES
```

**Option 2: Switch activation policy programmatically**

Normal app, opens window at launch, has menu, dock item:

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
```

Agent, no window at launch, can be a menu bar app if a status item is set:

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
```

You could set up a `@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor` and switch it in `applicationWillFinishLaunching(_:)`.

Like this:

**App.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
   
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        Settings {
            SettingsView()
        }
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import AppKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let isAgent = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "activationIsAgent")
        print("isAgent: \(isAgent)")
        if isAgent {
            NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
        } else {
            NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd still need a status bar item and put e.g. a toggling menu item for that UserDefaults key.

```
@AppStorage("activationIsAgent") private var activationIsAgent: Bool = false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already had the info.plist setting but was missing the `NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)` in my AppDelegate. There is no Dock icon anymore, however this still doesn't change the behavior of the first window being opened automatically. In my App's body I have two `Windows` (instead of the `WindowGroup`).

Comment: This doesn't answer the author's question at all.